# How to resolve dependencies recurcively with setup.py with local packages?

Tags: python, dependencies, package, local, setup.py

I am designing a python project like this:

```
packages/
    __init__.py
    setup.py
    requierment.txt         # Require package1
    commons/
        __init__.py
        setup.py
        requirement.txt
        Common_module.py
    package1/
        __init__.py
        setup.py
        requirement.txt      # Require commons
        Package1_module.py
```

When I do `pip install -r requierment.txt -t ./installation`, I would like it to create a folder installation in which I have `package1` and `commons` but it seems that it doesn't resolve the dependencies of `package1` leaving the installation with `package1` only.

How can I resolve dependencies recurcively?

After some research I found that `requierment.txt` should list all dependencies but I really don't want that.

So I tried the following:

```
from distutils.core import setup

required = []
with open('requirements.txt') as f:
     for line in f.readline():
         if not line.startswith('#'):
             required.append(line.rstrip())

setup(...
    install_requires=required)
```

But now, it looks for my dependencies on the Internet and not in my folder even if `required` is a list of local paths.

It's a simplified view of my issues, I can change my project achritecture a bit but let assume that the first requirement.txt cannot know the dependencies of the sub packages *(like the commons package)*.

Is there a nice way to resolve the dependencies recurcively?

Thanks!